# curl POST inside a for loop

Tags: shell-script, curl

the following works for create a single user:

```
curl -X POST  --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"user-name":"joe",
       "password": "cool",
       "role": [ "rest-reader", "rest-writer" ]
      }' \
  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/users
```

but it failed when inside a for loop to create multiple users (one at a time)

```
for i in john frank bob
do
  curl -X POST  --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"user-name":"$i",
       "password": "$i",
       "role": [ "rest-reader", "rest-writer" ]
      }' \
  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/users
done
```

where did i do wrong?

Comment: How do you know it's failing? Error code, message, ... Could you add that to the question?

Answer (score 7):

Your data string is enclosed in single quotes, but variables are not expanded within single quotes.
You may close the opening single quote with a `'`, add the double quoted variable with `"$i"` and open the single quoted string again with `'`:

```
for i in john frank bob
do
  curl -X POST  --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"user-name":"'"$i"'",
       "password": "'"$i"'",
       "role": [ "rest-reader", "rest-writer" ]
      }' \
  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/users
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

try removing quotes around $i

so, basically :

'{"username":"'$i'"}'
try this:

```
for i in john frank bob
do
  curl -X POST  --anyauth -u admin:admin --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"user-name":"'$i'",
       "password": "'$i'",
       "role": [ "rest-reader", "rest-writer" ]
      }' \
  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/users
done
```